# Read Values inside a html table row using jquery each

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get input values from below table but all I was getting undefined in console.
Below is HTML table

I add more rows dynamically.

```
<table id="t_payment_details" class="table" style="margin-left:15px;width:50%;">
    <tbody>
       <tr id="tr_payment_details" class="tr_payment_details">
            <td>Bank Account</td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:160px;" class="form-control" name="bank_account[]" class="bank_account"></td>
            <td>Reference Number</td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:160px;" class="form-control" name="payment_ref[]" class="payment_ref"></input></td>
            <td>Received Amount</td>
            <td><input type="text" style="width:100px;" class="form-control" name="received_amount[]" class="received_amount"></input></td>
            <td>Received Date</td>
            <td><input type="date" class="form-control" style="width:160px;" onchange='addRowToPaymentTable()' name="received_date[]" class="received_date"></input></td>
      </tr>     
    </tbody>        
</table>
```

Here is JQuery

```
$("tr.tr_payment_details").each(function() {

        var bank_account=$(this).find("input.bank_account").val();
        var payment_ref=$(this).find("input.payment_ref").val();
        var received_amount=$(this).find("input.received_amount").val();
        var received_date=$(this).find("input.received_date").val();


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is embarrassing. I didn't notice second class attribute in my input fields.

It was resolved after I merged both class attributes.
Sorry.